# Pandas search string containing "\"

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a python series and I am looking to search for a particular string format that contains a "\"

Currently I am using

```
 pd.str.contains("text1\text2").any()
```

however this doesn't work as \ is a reserved character.

I will really appreciate any inputs regarding this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parameter `regex=False` and in pandas is better dont use variable `pd`, because for load pandas into your namespace is used:

```
import pandas as pd

s.str.contains("text1\text2", regex=False).any()
```

Or escape by `\`:

```
s.str.contains("text1\\text2").any()
```

Sample:

```
s = pd.Series(['text1\text2','text1\text2\dd','text1'])
print (s)
0       text1\text2
1    text1\text2\dd
2             text1
dtype: object

print (s.str.contains("text1\text2", regex=False))
0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool

print (s.str.contains("text1\\text2"))
0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks that is perfect, though option number 2 doesn't work. I already tried it but your option 1 is perfect.